# JQuery Syntax Checker

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know of any JQuery syntax validators or checkers? The braces are killing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JSLint** and a live demo site **JSFiddle** will give you the ability to make sure something is valid and runs properly.

As said, most IDE's will validate your Javascript. Eclipse, Netbeans, PHPEd and so on all have javascript checkers.

Comment: i have heard of jslint, but not jsfiddler

Comment: JSfiddler allows you to select a JS library such as jQuery, input some HTML and write some javascript to execute against your HTML.

Answer (score 11):

Check out JSLint for validating JS code:

http://www.jslint.com/

Warning: JSLint will hurt your feelings

Comment: and JS lint is great with making your code look proper too.  Just define the global variable $ and JSLint will check your JS code.

Comment: Caveat: JSlint is distributed under a non-free license ("can only be used for good"), so you can't host it in most open-source projects.

Answer (score 1):

It's JavaScript. Any IDE with JavaScript syntax checker should do.
NetBeans has one.

Comment: So has Eclipse and KomodoEdit.

Comment: Visual Studio 2008 / 2010 does too.